# Issue with KOMA fontsize=10.5pt option and onehalfspacing setting for setspace

Tags: fontsize, koma-script, setspace

My document isn't compiling anymore as soon as I use a fraction as fontsize in `\documentclass[fontsize=10.5pt]{scrartcl}`.
Compilation breaks at `\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}` with the error message

```
Missing \begin{document}.
```

Comment: You need package `scrhack`  as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}` simply use these lines:

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.25}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to load package `scrhack` in order to get `onehalfspacing` to work with non-integr font sizes.

[image: texsxKomaSetspace]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10.5pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{p{1em}p{1em}p{1em}}
    \KOMAoptions{fontsize=10pt} M \par M &
    M  \par M&
    \KOMAoptions{fontsize=11pt}M  \par M
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this doesn't compile and brings up the same error message at line 6: `Missing \begin{document}. \begin`

Comment: @user3105453 If this would not compile, i wouldn't have posted it as an answer. Do you have an up to date TeX distribution?

Comment: I just updated from TeX Live 2014 to 2015 and now it's compiling without errors, thanks. The answer below, however, works even with older distributions.